# How to re-render React Native Web Swiper based on State change?

Tags: react-native, swiper.js

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-swiper) package to create a `Swiper` in React Native.
I used static data and it is working, but now I'm fetching data from server and save it in the state as an `Array`. 
The problem is when mapping the data inside the swiper to create dynamic sliders, it is not showing anything, but if I do it outside of the Swiper it is rendering.

How can I solve this problem?

```
 <Swiper
    from={0}
    minDistanceForAction={0.1}
    controlsProps={{
        dotsTouchable: true,
        prevPos: 'left',
        nextPos: 'right',
        nextTitle: '',
        prevTitle: '',
        dotsWrapperStyle: { marginTop: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(8), width: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(7), height: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(7), borderRadius: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(7) },
                                dotActiveStyle: { width: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(7), height: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(7), borderRadius: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(7) },
                            }}
 >

 {
   this.state.notifications.map((notif, index) => {
      return (
          <View style={[styless.slideContainer]}>

                                            <Card transparent style={{
                                                flex: 0,
                                                elevation: 3,
                                                shadowColor: "#000",
                                                shadowOpacity: 0.1,
                                                shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
                                                shadowRadius: 1.0,

                                            }}>
                                                <CardItem
                                                    style={{ paddingTop: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(14), paddingLeft: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(14), paddingBottom: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(14) }}
                                                >
                                                    <Left>
                                                        <View style={{
                                                            width: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(60),
                                                            height: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(60),
                                                            borderRadius: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(60) / 2,
                                                            margin: 0,
                                                            padding: 0,
                                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                                            backgroundColor: '#FF004E',
                                                            elevation: 5,
                                                            shadowColor: "#000",
                                                            shadowOpacity: 0.1,
                                                            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(2) },
                                                            shadowRadius: 1.0,
                                                        }}>
                                                            <Image source={bmwerror} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                                                        </View>
                                                        <Body style={{ marginLeft: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(23) }}>
                                                            <Text style={styles.cardUpperText}>{notif.msg}</Text>
                                                            <Text style={styles.cardLowerText}>{notif.axle}{notif.side}</Text>
                                                        </Body>
                                                    </Left>
                                                </CardItem>
                                            </Card>

                                        </View>
      )
   })

 }
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the module:

> **Dynamic content**
>   The Swiper will not be re-rendered if slides state or props have changed. Slides must control their condition.

This means that you have to manage state change on your own through your slides and not through Swiper component.

EDIT:

So, you can create a custom Slide module to handle those slides coming from server as:

```
class Slide extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // your state for the slide component goes here....
}
render() {
    const { msg, axle, side } = this.props.notification; // destructure your notification prop being passed from the map method of parent component
    return (
        <View style={[styless.slideContainer]}>
            <Card transparent style={{
                flex: 0,
                elevation: 3,
                shadowColor: "#000",
                shadowOpacity: 0.1,
                shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
                shadowRadius: 1.0,

            }}>
                <CardItem
                    style={{ paddingTop: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(14), paddingLeft: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(14), paddingBottom: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(14) }}
                >
                    <Left>
                        <View style={{
                            width: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(60),
                            height: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(60),
                            borderRadius: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(60) / 2,
                            margin: 0,
                            padding: 0,
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            backgroundColor: '#FF004E',
                            elevation: 5,
                            shadowColor: "#000",
                            shadowOpacity: 0.1,
                            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: ScaleHelpers.CalcHeight(2) },
                            shadowRadius: 1.0,
                        }}>
                            <Image source={bmwerror} style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }} />
                        </View>
                        <Body style={{ marginLeft: ScaleHelpers.CalcWidth(23) }}>
                            {/* use your destructure constants where required */}
                            <Text style={styles.cardUpperText}>{msg}</Text> 
                            <Text style={styles.cardLowerText}>{axle}{side}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </Left>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>

        </View>
    );
}
}export default Slide;
```

I have mentioned in comments how you can take the required information out of the notifications object.
Now comes the sending part, in your map function just call your newly created Slide component and pass the notification object as a prop like this:

```
<Slide notification={notif}/>
```

Notice here, in `notification={notif}` notification would serve as the name of the prop in Slide component and there you have to extract information from `this.props.notification` object as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? I didn't understand how to do it

Comment: Show your implementation of Swiper and share some code related to your slides. Otherwise you can also find the implementation on their documentation.

Comment: I will share the general structure .

Comment: I shared my code, the problem is that I don't know how many sliders I will have, the number is generated through some calculations from backend

Comment: Thats absolutely fine, but you should have some component which will be showing those dynamic slides coming from backend, I believe. Share implementation of that component, specifically I am talking that "//some views" part.

Comment: I tried to define the part inside the Swiper in a different component but I did't managed to make it render. I will try to add the code it's a little long

Comment: Thank you sir, do you mean the state in my first Component where i'm geeting data ?

Comment: State mentioned in the comment of the code above, refers to the state of the Slide component.

Comment: I tried your solution, I created a Slide component and moved the code to that component but it's not working. It's showing nothing.